# Solve $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=f(x-1)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, functional-equations

I am trying to find a function such that

$\dfrac{d}{dx}f(x)=f(x-1)$

Is there such function other than $0$ ?

Comment: $e^{\Omega x}$ where $\Omega \sim 0.5671432904097838729999686622$ is the root of the equation $\Omega e^{\Omega} = 1$ (also known as [Omega constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_constant)).

Answer (score 5):

Certainly. Let $b$ be the unique real number such that $b=e^{-b}.$ Then for any real $a,$ the function $$f(x)=ae^{bx}$$ satisfies the desired property. In fact, for real-valued functions on the reals, *only* functions of this form will satisfy the desired property. (As achillehui points out in the comments, there are other alternatives if we consider complex-valued functions.)

In particular, $b=W(1)$, where $W$ is the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). $W(1)$ is also sometimes known as the [Omega constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Special_values).

Comment: Is there any way to see that b exists? Does it have to do with intermediate value theorem?

Comment: Complex roots of the equation $b e^b = 1$ also generate solutions for the delayed ODE. e.g. $b e^b = 1$ has a root at $\sim -1.533913319793575 + i4.375185153061898$. This corresponds to a solution $f(x) \sim e^{-1.533913319793575 x} \cos(4.375185153061898 x)$.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, I already know how to see that b exists. Just plot Exp(-x) and x on the same graph and b is the unique point where these functions cross.

Comment: @Adam: The intermediate Value Theorem is the simplest way to go. Note that the function $x\mapsto e^{-x}-x$ is strictly decreasing and continuous, that $0\mapsto 1,$ and that $1\mapsto -\frac1e-1,$ so there is a unique zero lying between $x=0$ and $x=1.$

Comment: @achillehui: Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an intuition(!): Let us write $D = \frac{d}{dx}$. If $f$ is analytic,

$$ f(x+h) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{h^{n}}{n!} D^{n} f(x) = e^{hD} f(x) $$

at least in a formal sense (and a genuine sense in view of functional-analysis context). So if you want to solve the equation

$$ Df(x) = f(x-1) = e^{-D}f(x), $$

you are tempted to solve the equation $D = e^{-D}$, or equivalently, $De^{D} = 1$. Since an eigenfunction of $D$ corresponding to an eigenvalue $\lambda$ is $e^{\lambda x}$, passing to this eigenfunction, it amounts to solve the equation $\lambda e^{\lambda} = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f : [0;1]$ is any smooth function with $f^{(k+1)}(1) = f^{(k)}(0)$ for all $k$, then we can extend it to a function $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ by induction with $f(x) = f(1) + \int_0^{x-1} f(t)dt$ if $x \ge 1$ and $f(x) = f'(x+1)$ if $x \le 0$. This new function is a solution to $f'(x) = f(x-1)$.

Conversely, if $f$ is a solution, its restriction to $[0;1]$ is smooth and satifies $f^{(k+1)}(1) = f^{(k)}(0)$ for all $k$, and $f$ is the extension of its restriction. So you actually have a bijection between solutions and smooth functions on $[0;1]$ satisfying $f^{(k+1)}(1) = f^{(k)}(0)$ for all $k$.

Answer (score 0):

$f (x)=ce^{ax}$ will give solutions as well.  Both differentiation and horizontal shift of the function will act to scale the initial function and you can solve for $a $